# I need help making a Tic Tac Toe game. Python

Tags: python

Can I get some help making the computer's choice and finishing this program, I'm confused on what I have to do still... maybe a while loop at the end with the functions? I'm very confused on how to make the computer's choice. So far the player's choice, board and the wincheck probably works I just need everything else to work before I can test it out. For some reason when I try using 1 on the board it gives me a value error.

```
import random
board = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Computer = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
player = []
pc = []
wincheck = []
def WinCheck():
    for i in range(0,9):
        o = player.count[i]
        if o == 1:
            wincheck.append[i]
        else:
            continue

    if wincheck == [1,2,3]:
        print("You Win! The board will reset in 5 seconds!")
        reset()    
    elif wincheck == [4,5,6]:
        print("You Win! The board will reset in 5 seconds!")
        reset()
    elif wincheck == [7,8,9]:
        print("You Win! The board will reset in 5 seconds!")
        reset()
    elif wincheck == [1,4,7]:
        print("You Win! The board will reset in 5 seconds!")
        reset()
    elif wincheck == [2,5,8]:
        print("You Win! The board will reset in 5 seconds!")
        reset()
    elif wincheck == [3,6,9]:
        print("You Win! The board will reset in 5 seconds!")
        reset()
    elif wincheck == [1,5,9]:
        print("You Win! The board will reset in 5 seconds!")
        reset()
    elif wincheck == [3,5,7]:
        print("You Win! The board will reset in 5 seconds!")
        reset()


def draw():

    print ("\n" , "|",board[0],"|",board[1],"|",board[2], "|")
    print ("\n", "--------")
    print ("\n", "|",board[3],"|",board[4],"|",board[5], "|")
    print ("\n", "--------")
    print ("\n", "|", board[6],"|", board[7],"|", board[8], "|" , " \n")


#Resets the board
def reset():
    while True:
        board = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        time.sleep(5)
        break

#Choosing a number from the board
def ChooseNum():
    while 1 == 1:
        while True:
            print('Where do you want to place you X')
            choice = input('')
            try:
                choice = int(choice)
            except ValueError:
                print("You didn't enter a number... Try again")
                break

            x = board.index(choice)
            Computer.remove(x)
            board.remove(choice)
            board.insert(x,'X')
            print(Computer)
            draw()




def CompChoice():
    while 1 == 1:
        while True:
            compchoice = random.choice(board)
            o = board.index(compchoice)
            Computer.remove(o)
            board.remove(compchoice)
            board.insert(o,'O')
            print(Computer)
            draw()

draw()
ChooseNum()
```

Comment: If your computer always makes the optimal choice, the player will never win (only loss and draw). What do you really expect ? A computer making some "mistakes" to let opportunities (then you may need some random feature) or an unbreakable AI ?

Comment: Depends what you are trying to do. Copy your `ChooseNum` function, but pick a random number instead of a `input` and use the same logic?

Comment: also, for some odd reason whenever i put in 1 for the player's choice it comes up as a value error

Answer (score 1):

Now you have a way to make a computer move, from my comment, notice this code:

```
Computer.remove(x)
board.remove(choice)
```

For one, you use the index `x` you found out, for the other you use the value.

`remove` removes "**the first item from the list whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item**." This will give you a `ValueError` if it can't find the value you tell it to look for.

This gives your error.
You need to remove the choice from the list:

```
Computer.remove(choice)
board.remove(choice)
```

You have a similar problem in the computer choice function.
In order to get this to play tic-tac-toe with you you need to make a few changes.
To point you on the way: remove the while loops from the functions, and use something like this to play:

```
draw()
while any(i not in ['X', 'O'] for i in board):
  ChooseNum()
  CompChoice()
```

You might find it easier if you just have one `board` - you are trying to maintain the same information in both your lists.
You also need to check a move is legal - you can't go to a spot with an `'X'` or `'O'`.
Fianlly, you might want to check if someone has won.

Comment: Put what? The last bit? Instead of your last two lines. The check for winners? We'd need to tidy up your win check game - you can make it check the player or the computer and print the right message